# SSRS 2008: Check array is empty in custom code

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Not totally new to SSRS but completely new to custom code. I have a function that I need to use to check if all parameters are null or blank. I was able to figure out how to do this with two of the fields but I am not sure how to handle doing this with the rest of the parameters as they are I believe arrays since the allow multiple values. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Any resources such as books or sites that could help me in the future would also be a big plus as almost all the search results I get are for everything BUT handling things in custom code.

```
Function NoParameters(StartDate as DateTime, EndDate as DateTime) As Boolean
Dim RetValue as Boolean
RetValue = "False"
If(StartDate = Nothing And EndDate = Nothing)
RetValue = "True"
Else
RetValue = "False"
End If
Return RetValue
End Function
```

To clarify all parameters are set to allow null or blank. Doing this so that the user has to select at least ONE parameter but can also select any and all parameters. Handling the parameters on the SQL side with a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass the count of the parameter to your function and check if it's zero I guess.

pass in `Parameters!myParameter.Count`

If I have misunderstood let me know and show how you currently call the custom code.

Having said all that if the parameters are required, you should not be able to run the report anyway?

Comment: The parameters are actually not required. I am trying to do handle a one or many situation here. Where the user has to select at least one parameter but not specifically any parameter just at least one of them or all of them. I am handling the parameters on the SQL side with a dynamic query.

Comment: Ah OK. Well this answer should work then. Then `.Count(0)` shows you how many values have been selected from a multivalue parameter.

Comment: So basically you are saying in the field that I am using to run the custom function I could pass something like this. `=Code.NoParameters(Parameters!StartDate.Value,Parameters!EndDate.Value,Parameters!ClientCode.Count)` and then check in the custom code if the `Variable < 1` ?

Comment: correct. Unfortunately you cannot loop thru the parameters collection in code so you need to specify each parameter . You can pass the entire collection in as a single parameter and then reference each parameter by name. This might be a little cleaner, personal choice I guess. There is some info about working with parameters in custom code in the SSRS documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms155798(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Should I declare the incoming variable as an Integer? `Function NoParameters(StartDate as DateTime, EndDate as DateTime, ClientCode as Integer) As Boolean`

Comment: Yes as you are passing a number. You are passing just the `.Count()` so by the time it hits your custom code all you have passed is a number.

Comment: Ok so small issue it seems that since I am allowing multiple values I am not allowed to set Allow null value. Because of this the only other option is Allow blank value. Which automatically sets the count of the parameter to 1. I am thinking a possible solution might be to instead of passing Parameters!ClientCode.Count would be to pass the very first value in the array and see if it equals Nothing? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can reference the first value with `Parameters!ClientCode.Value(0)`

Comment: Perfect that worked! Amazing. One last thing that I might need to make a separate post for but you might know. Is there a way to use a Boolean Parameter to stop a Dataset from running the stored procedure? I had tried using this `If IsEmpty = False EXEC sp_grand_smslog_processing` but this fails to run.

Comment: That should be asked separately but I will be able to answer